# Git invert staging area

Tags: git, staging, git-stage

I have got changes in my staging area, and others not staged yet (some files have changes both in and out the staging area). **I would like to invert the content of the staging area and the changes which are not staged. Does a shortcut exist in order to do that**, without doing more complex actions like local side-branch commits, or diffs, or stashes [etc.]? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the shortest way to swap staged and unstaged changes in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573410/what-is-the-shortest-way-to-swap-staged-and-unstaged-changes-in-git)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the link. Not the same search terms, but the same issue, indeed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the shortest way to swap staged and unstaged changes in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573410/what-is-the-shortest-way-to-swap-staged-and-unstaged-changes-in-git)

Answer (score 6):

Here’s how I do it:

1. Commit the index to a temporary commit
2. Commit the remainder to a secondary temporary commit
3. Switch the order of the commits with interactive rebase
4. Mixed reset
5. Soft reset

It can be typed out manually pretty fast, especially if you use Vim for commit messages:

```sh
git commit -m tmp1
git add . # optionally with `git add -u` if there are deletions
git commit -m tmp2
git rebase -i HEAD~2 # swap the order of the commits; `ddp:wq` in vi
git reset HEAD~1
git reset HEAD~1 --soft
```

Comment: I like this except for the manual edit to swap the commits. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203562/programmatically-swap-last-two-commits

Comment: Good point.  But the problem for me personally is I don't do this enough to write a shortcut script and remember what it's called and how it works.  Interactive rebasing I do almost every day and it's extremely intuitive and efficient for me.

Answer (score 5):

There’s probably more than one way to do this, but I think I would take this approach – there’s currently no pre-built shortcut to this, but you could pretty easily write your own script to follow this process:

1. Generate a patch for the stuff that is currently in your working directory but not in your index yet (things you haven’t done `git add` for)

   ```sh
   git diff-files -p > /tmp/unstaged.patch
   ```
2. Generate a patch for what you’ve already added to the index against your current `HEAD`

   ```sh
   git diff-index --cached -p HEAD > /tmp/staged.patch
   ```
3. Reset your index and working directory to your `HEAD`

   ```sh
   git reset --hard HEAD
   ```
4. Apply your unstaged patch to both your working directory and your index, resulting in those changes being staged

   ```sh
   git apply --index /tmp/unstaged.patch
   ```
5. Apply your staged patch against only your working directory

   ```sh
   git apply /tmp/staged.patch
   ```

Depending on the exact nature of your changes, steps 4 and/or 5 may result in some merge conflicts that you need to resolve by hand, but I’m not sure there’s a clean way to completely avoid that possibility.

You could probably use `git stash` to accomplish steps 1 and 4 instead of the above commands, but I’m not sure that would really gain you anything…

Also, you may want to review the man pages for the `git diff-*` and `git apply` commands first to see if there are other options that might make sense for you to use.

Answer (score 4):

Based on gtd's answer and the ability to script inverting the commits this is what I'm using now:

```
[alias]                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    swaplast = !git tag _invert && git reset --hard HEAD~2 && git cherry-pick _invert _invert~1 && git tag -d _invert                                                                                            
    invertindex = !git commit -m tmp1 && git add -A && git commit -m tmp2 && git swaplast && git reset HEAD~1 && git reset HEAD~1 --soft
```

Posted on my blog here: http://blog.ericwoodruff.me/2013/12/inverting-git-index.html

Comment: I’ve done some investigation and testing and this is my unauthorized documentation: `swaplast` swaps the last and one-before-last commit. Attention: It discards uncommitted changes without notice. `invertindex` swaps staged and unstaged changes, including untracked files.

Comment: If for some reason this fails, you may need to run `git cherry-pick --abort` before you can run `git invertindex` again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've turned these into separate [git swaplast](https://github.com/inkarkat/git-extensions/blob/master/git-swaplast) and [git invertstage](https://github.com/inkarkat/git-extensions/blob/master/git-invertstage) scripts (you'll also need [git existsbr](https://github.com/inkarkat/git-extensions/blob/master/git-existsbr)) that also offer continuation (with `--continue`) in case of conflicts. The original aliases just abort and leave the user stranded.

Comment: I changed `git add -A` to `git add -u` so it won't try to commit the untracked files.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to solve this issue.

First `git reset` which will remove all the files from 'staging' to 'files not staged for commit'. The files that are in both 'staging' and 'files not staged for commit' will keep your most recent changes that are currently in your 'files not staged for commit'

then

`git add /path/to/file` the specific files you need to add to staging

Not exactly a short-cut, but it gets the job done

Inversely, After you `git reset`, you could `git checkout /path/to/file` for the files that are currently 'not staged for commit' which you don't want to add to staging. This will remove specific files from 'not staged to commit'

then run `git add .` which will add all files in 'not staged for commit' to 'staging' - whichever is easier for your situation

Comment: Actually, I would precisely prefer not to do that by hand, because the limit between staged and non-staged is rather complex: even inside some files, some lines are staged and other non-staged.

Comment: Did you seem my recent edit regarding files both staged and not staged?

Comment: What do you mean by "you could git checkout the files you don't want [...]"? it is pretty obscure to me...

Comment: I'll try that but currently I don't understand how it could get the job done.