# Programmatically swap last two commits

Tags: git

I know how to swap the last two commits using `git rebase` interactively (`git rebase -i HEAD~2`, `ddjp:x` in Vim), but I'd like to do it programmatically with a wrapper script since it's something I end up doing relatively often.

To be more concrete, I want to rewrite history from

```
A---B---C---D HEAD
```

to

```
A---B---D---C HEAD
```

in an entirely scripted manner. Ideally, if the swap fails, it should either allow me to fix it interactively or just give up and tell me to do it manually.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This should do it:

```
git tag old
git reset --hard HEAD~2
git cherry-pick old
git cherry-pick old~1
git tag -d old
```

First, you tag the place where you are as `old`, then go back two commits, `git cherry-pick` the commits in the other order, and delete the `old` tag.

Comment: You can combine as `git cherry-pick old old~1`

Comment: FYI: this doesn't completely work because `git reset HEAD~2` will leave uncommitted changes, causing `cherry-pick` to fail.

Comment: I would rather use a git reset --keep instead of git reset --hard as you're going to make side effect to current working copy by executing this command

Comment: FYI, I made this script a bit more error-proof in this gist : https://gist.github.com/fcamblor/3202f6ca617feac902c4c267a48e0d8b

Answer (score 8):

Since you want to do this often, I assume your going to want to reduce to a single step process. I'll make this a bit educational though and break it down.

## IMPORTANT

Don't do this sort of thing on any commits that have already been shared with other developer, or pushed to a remote. Rewriting shared history is a recipe for disaster.

That public service announcement aside...

### Step 1

```
A---B---C---D (master, HEAD, ORIG_HEAD)

git rebase --quiet --onto HEAD~2 HEAD~1 HEAD
```

This takes whatever is in HEAD that isn't in HEAD~1, and applies it to HEAD~2. After running this rebase, you will have this history. Keep in mind that `git-rebase --onto` will throw you into a headless state. (I've got `--quiet` in there so the final command doesn't spit a wall of text to your screen).

```
A---B---C---D (master, ORIG_HEAD)
     \
      D'  (HEAD)
```

Now we need to get `C` applied after `D'`, for this we can use `git-cherry-pick`. When a `git-rebase --onto` is performed as it was above, the original commit history before the rebase is saved in `ORIG_HEAD` because git wont change it until you do some other activity. This is useful in case you screw up a rebase, but we'll use it here to cherry-pick.

### Step 2

```
git cherry-pick ORIG_HEAD~1

A---B---C---D (master, ORIG_HEAD)
     \
      D'---C'  (HEAD)
```

The state of HEAD is now exactly as you wanted, with just two commands. I assume this will usually take place from within a branch, and that you'll want to update that branch with the new order of commits. If I'm wrong about that, then that's it and your done. If you do want update the branch you were on, there are a couple ways to do that.

The simplest to do manually would be to do the following...

```
git log -1    ###copy the the SHA1
git checkout master
git reset --hard <SHA1>
```

However the whole point is automation, and there ways of doing this that are less obvious, but require fewer commands.

### Step 3

```
git update-ref refs/heads/master $(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

By using `git-rev-parse`, I get only the commit of HEAD and nothing else. Applying that to `git-update-ref, I can "reset" the master branch without having to check it out first. Now that master is set properly, I can go ahead and checkout master (the point of the update-ref is to reduce the number of steps involved for the eventual alias/bash script).

### Step 4

```
git checkout --quiet master
```

Again, I pass `--quiet` so as to reduce the amount of text dumped on the screen after each command.

### Bash Script

If you wanted to do this as a bash script, you could automate the entire process even further, and make it work dynamically on whatever branch you want, not just master.

```
#!/bin/bash
branch=$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD)
git rebase --onto HEAD~2 HEAD~1 HEAD
git cherry-pick ORIG_HEAD~1
git update-ref refs/heads/$branch $(git rev-parse HEAD)
git checkout --quiet $branch
```

### Git Alias

That said, this is just as easily dumped into a git alias without having to actually create a file for the bash script. Creating the file and setting up the alias isn't hard by any means, but it's another thing to understand, and many people don't. Here's a simple git alias, run this command once..

```
git config --global alias.flip-last "!branch=$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD); git rebase --quiet --onto HEAD~2 HEAD~1 HEAD; git cherry-pick ORIG_HEAD~1; git update-ref refs/heads/$branch $(git rev-parse HEAD); git checkout --quiet $branch"
```

Now anytime you want to flip your last two commits, just use...

```
git flip-last
```

### GitHub Gist

This was an interesting little script to write, I've thrown it up on a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/eddiemoya/5456992). Feel free to fork it, make changes, star it, whatever.

https://gist.github.com/eddiemoya/5456992

Answer (score 3):

For reference, this is the script I ended up using:

```
. "$(git --exec-path)/git-sh-setup"
require_clean_work_tree swap2

if [ -e $GIT_DIR/sequencer ]; then
    die "Cherry-pick already in progress; swap aborted"
fi

HEAD=`git rev-list --max-count=1 HEAD`
git reset --hard HEAD~2
if git cherry-pick $HEAD $HEAD^; then
    echo "Successfully swapped top two commits."
else
    git cherry-pick --abort
    git reset --hard $HEAD
    die "Failed to swap top two commits."
fi
```