# Git Push to Remote Issue

Tags: git

How do I push a single commit to the repo? specificially the one on top 388c85.
When I try to push to remote repo it picks the two commits below.

Git Log

```
commit 388c85ccb56164c6f0c91584aa9251b87acc7f89
Author: test <test@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 6 16:38:50 2016 -0400

Login Page updates

commit 3d4b4da976bfefff4a18bfbcbfb9bdaa35d7c991
Author: test <test@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 6 13:09:19 2016 -0400

initial commit this mostly include user interface updates
```

Comment: I have already tried this "git push -u origin 388c85ccb56164c6f0c91584aa9251b87acc7f89:BES-22"

Comment: got an error "error: unable to push to unqualified destination: BES-22
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
"

Comment: `git cherry-pick` is what you need. `git rebase` also works but is not so easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you have something like this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E
     \               \- master
      \- origin/master
```

and you want to add commit `E` to your remote repository, but you don't want `C` and `D`.

Then you should cherry-pick `E`:

```
git checkout B # use for instance the sha1 of this commit
git checkout -B BES-22 # it creates the branch BES-22 locally and puts you on it
git cherry-pick E
```

At this point you have:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E
      \ -- E'       \-master
       \    \- BES-22
        \- origin/master
```

So you can push:

```
git push origin BES-22
```

---

In particular, note that:

- Since commits are immutable in Git, the `cherry-pick` created a brand new commit `E'`
- If you have the error `error: unable to push to unqualified destination: BES-22 The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.`, it more or less means that branch `BES-22` doesn't exist on the remote. Using `git push origin <branch>` instead of `git push origin <sha1>:<unexisting remote branch>` should fix it

Comment: This answer is right (and I've upvoted it), but the drawing should have `E'` pointing back to commit `B`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting this mistake! (I've just fixed it).

Answer (score 0):

try below command

```
git push <remotename> <commit SHA>:<remotebranchname>
```

Example

```
git push origin 388c85ccb56164c6f0c91584aa9251b87acc7f89:master
```

In above case `master` is your branch to push.

Comment: I have tried this git push origin 388c85ccb56164c6f0c91584aa9251b87acc7f89:BES-22, but it pushes the two commits instead of one

Answer (score 0):

`git` always pushes all the commits upto the HEAD (Given commit hash). So in your case when you do `git push` all the commits prior to the `HEAD` are pushed and even if you do `git push origin 388c85ccb56164c6f0c91584aa9251b87acc7f89:master` it would push all commits upto `388c85ccb56164c6f0c91584aa9251b87acc7f89`. One thing you can do is reorder your commit history so that the history looks like below:

```
commit 3d4b4da976bfefff4a18bfbcbfb9bdaa35d7c991
Author: test <test@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 6 13:09:19 2016 -0400

initial commit this mostly include user interface updates

commit 388c85ccb56164c6f0c91584aa9251b87acc7f89
Author: test <test@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 6 16:38:50 2016 -0400

Login Page updates
```

Now if you do `git push origin 388c85ccb56164c6f0c91584aa9251b87acc7f89:master` only `388c85ccb56164c6f0c91584aa9251b87acc7f89` commit will be pushed and not `3d4b4da976bfefff4a18bfbcbfb9bdaa35d7c991`

In order to re-order git commits, you can Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16203754/3878940 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/4981173/3878940