# Bring last git commit from branch to another prior the fork

Tags: git

I have this situation:

```
X-X-X-X-X-X-K-Y develop
            |-Z-X-X-X-W experimental
```

I want to bringh the changes made in commit Y from the fist branch to the second and put it before the first commit in the second, Z
I want then this:

```
X-X-X-X-X-X-K-Y develop
              |-Z-X-X-X-W experimental
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the canonical situation where one would use rebase:

```
$ git checkout experimental
$ git rebase develop
```

Comment: That won't bring Y at the first position, will it?

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. I read the whole book from the git-scm but a direct example with a direct answer is better for newbie. Maybe can be useful for other people. :)

Comment: @toydarian: No it wouldn't. The result looks just like the second tree in the question.

Answer (score 1):

first you have to cherry-pick Y to experimental.

Presuming you are on experimental branch: `git cherry-pick Y`

Then experimental looks like this:

```
Z-X-X-X-W-Y
```

Then you have to reorder the commits with `git rebase -i Y^ experimental`
That will bring up the interactive mode of git rebase. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740537/reordering-of-commits) for more information.

The commands you have to use in the interactive mode look like this:

```
pick Y
pick Z
pick X
# all Xs
pick W
```

Check the man page of `git-cherry-pick`, so you get it rigth. And backup your repo before ;-)

Comment: Can you explain me the differences with the reply of @EricSchaefer? Because I tried its answer and it works for me perfectly! I'm asking just to learn something more :)

Comment: Its a lot more complicated ;) – I thought, Y would be added to the "end" of the branch, but that was a mistake. Erics way is the best one.