# git, reorder commits in messed up branches

Tags: git

I've got a git repo that I would like to restructure completely.

All in all I've got three features, let's call them feature `A`, `B`, `C`, that I've been working on for the past few weeks. Unfortunately I've been a bit unthoughtful regarding how to use branches to split my working on the features correctly, and I somehow also jumped from feature to feature even between commits.

So now I've got three branches `A_devel`, `B_devel`, `C_devel` and in each branch a bunch of commits that belong to each of the three features. Some commits of feature `A` also containing some changes for feature `B` in `B_devel`, some of `B` with changes for `A` in `C_devel` and so on. Some commits are even in the `master` branch, containing changes for any of the features. And all the commits are also already pushed to `origin`.

It's a complete chaos...

... that I would like to clean up now.

At least I can see from the commit messages and in some cases just from the code diffs what I've been working on in every particular commit. So I know which commit belongs to which feature. I just need to know how to actually **move** the commits to the corresponding correct branch.

//edit: by the way, I have to mention that I'm the only one working on this repo, locally as well as on origin. So most likely no one would have problems with a changed history... just in case that's going to be necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reordering of commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740537/reordering-of-commits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note the following before reading the rest of the answer:

1. git reset or rebase both do history rewriting, so they should not be used if the history was published. This shouldn't be a problem in your case, since you are the only one using the repo.
2. cherry-pick, as of v1.7.1, can cherry-pick multiple commits, so you can use this to "yank" more than one commit out.

So my suggested strategy would be something as follows. Consider the following structure which has a mish-mash of changes related to features A and B on two branches:

```
      A1--A2--B1--B2--A3 (A_Devel HEAD)
     /
o-o-X (master HEAD)
     \ 
      B3--B4--A4--B5 (B_Devel HEAD)
```

what we want is:

```
      A1--A2--A3--A4 (A_Devel HEAD)
     /
o-o-X (master HEAD)
     \ 
      B1--B2--B3--B4--B5 (B_Devel HEAD)
```

---

#### Make sure that all feature branches have all relevant commits + some unneeded ones

Copy all commit related to feature A to A_Devel from B_Devel:

1. `git checkout A_Devel`
2. `git cherry-pick A4`

giving

```
      A1--A2--B1--B2--A3--A4 (A_Devel HEAD)
     /
o-o-X (master HEAD)
     \ 
      B3--B4--A4--B5 (B_Devel HEAD)
```

---

1. `git checkout B_Devel`
2. `git cherry-pick B1 B2`

giving

```
      A1--A2--B1--B2--A3--A4 (A_Devel HEAD)
     /
o-o-X (master HEAD)
     \ 
      B3--B4--A4--B5--B1--B2 (B_Devel HEAD)
```

---

---

#### Now remove the irrelevant commits

1. `git checkout A_Devel`
2. `git rebase -i HEAD~~~~`   (we wanna remove B1, B2)
3. Editor opens up with:

   `pick B1
   pick B2
   pick A3
   pick A4`

Delete the first two lines and save and exit from editor. Wait for rebase to finish.

Now we'll have:

```
      A1--A2--A3--A4 (A_Devel HEAD)
     /
o-o-X (master HEAD)
     \ 
      B3--B4--A4--B5--B1--B2 (B_Devel HEAD)
```

---

Similarly, for branch B_Devel:

1. `git checkout B_Devel`
2. `git rebase -i HEAD~~~~~~`   (we wanna change stuff in the last 6 commits)
3. Editor opens up with:

   `pick B3
   pick B4
   pick A4
   pick B5
   pick B1
   pick B2`

delete the line with A1 and reorder the remaining 'B' changes so that they look like:

```
 pick B1
 pick B2
 pick B3
 pick B4
 pick B5
```

Save, exit, wait for rebase to finish which will finally give us:

```
      A1--A2--A3--A4 (A_Devel HEAD)
     /
o-o-X (master HEAD)
     \ 
      B1--B2--B3--B4--B5 (B_Devel HEAD)
```

Comment: Yepp, have been doing it like this now. Worked pretty well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not a nice solution, but if you're going through the whole log, you could theoretically use a combination of `git cherry-pick <commithash>` to get one commit from one branch to another one, and `git rebase -i` (interactive rebase) to reorder commits in your branch.

[Read more on this here.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)