How to reorder commits to make a squash in git?
When doing interactive rebase for making squash and merge some commits into one I realized that when commits are not correlative this can not be done properly, this is an example suppossing we have 5 commits and we want to commit 2 with 4 and 5:
rebase -i HEAD~5
pick hash1 commit message 1
pick hash2 commit message 2
pick hash3 commit message 3
squash? hash4 commit message 4
squash? hash5 commit message 5

The problem is that squash applies to previous commit and in this example 3rd commit is on the way.
Is there a way to alter commit order to easily make the wanted squash?
Note: This is just an example, the question applies to N commits when they are unordered.

For the example you give, you can simply re-order the lines in your editor.  eg, put lines 4 and 5 directly after line 2.  Whether line 3 goes before or after depends on where you want that commit in the new history.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740537/reordering-of-commits , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+reorder+commits

Disregarding conflicts, you can simply reorder the lines in your editor:
pick oid1 commit summary 1
pick oid2 commit summary 2
squash oid4 commit summary 4
squash oid5 commit summary 5
pick oid3 commit summary 3


Thank you! I just missed that commits could be reordered this way
