# Git Gui error - Failed to stage selected line ... patch does not apply

Tags: git, git-gui

I use Git Gui, and very infrequently when I try to stage selected lines, I get an error message box:

```
Failed to stage selected line.
error: patch failed: Foo/Bar.json:103
error: Foo/Bar.json: patch does not apply
```

Staging the entire file works, however.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this error?
Has anyone else encountered it when using Git Gui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure to use a recent Git (latest 2.23) minimal.
As I explain in "[Why does `git stash -p` sometimes fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331025/6309)", [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) (called by git-gui) has had a series of improvement since Git 2.17 (Q2 2018).

> This happens for me any time I try to split a hunk into smaller hunks that are too close together (less than 3 lines between changes).
>   The short explanation is that the patch has context lines in it that conflict with your local changes.

See more at "[Git stash apply did not return working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42065060/6309)".
Playing with the [`diff.context` could help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40420650/6309), minimizing the hunk context footprint.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was because I had enabled `-w` as a diff parameter. Removing it fixed the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I could add the lines when I reduce the 'context lines' to one in the Gui-Options (Menu Edit). This requires restarting the GUI. You can also change manually the value to zero.

[image]