# git bash shell on Windows "Your edited hunk does not apply"

Tags: git, interactive, git-add

I have a very frustrating error when trying to manually edit hunks while using the command:

```
git add -p
```

I have already looked through many of the existing questions on this site, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268596/git-add-interactive-your-edited-hunk-does-not-apply), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500645/editing-git-patch-gives-your-edited-hunk-does-not-apply).

I am at the point where I try to manually edit a hunk, **make no changes** to the file opened by git for manual editing, and still getting the error "Your edited hunk does not apply".

I thought this might have to do with CRLF vs. LF EOL characters. I am editing in Notepad++, and I can see that all of my line endings are CRLF. I naively tried to change all the line endings to LF, but to no avail.

I can also see that all context lines have leading spaces, so that isn't the issue either. Furthermore, I have:

```
git --global core.autocrlf
```

set to `true`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

**Edit:** According to VonC's answer, in my specific case I have a permission + content diff. Does this still mean I cannot do:

```
git add -p
```

If it were only a permission diff, I understand why this wouldn't be necessary, and the interactive option must be dropped; but in this case, is there a way to still do an interactive `add`?

Comment: Can you give the exact sequence of commands and other actions which lead to this error?

Comment: After running `git add -p`, I just type `e` to manually edit a hunk of code. `git` then opens an edit file for editing the hunk. I get the error even if I close this edit file without making any changes.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information. You might also want to add the step that you edit your code. It will also be helpful to give a more concrete example of the original edit and then later show how you edit the hunk.

Comment: Also, when you say that "git then opens an edit file", I assume you mean that git opens the file in vim. Is that correct?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have included all this information in my question. Note that I said git open my edit file in Notepad++ (my default editor for .txt files). I also say that I get the error even after no changes were made to the hunk edit file.

Comment: You still can make a `git add -p` for any file with content diff: `git add -p -- a_file_with_content_diff`.

Comment: @VonC this is exactly what is not working for me

Comment: Hence the need for a new question clearly illustrating the issue

Comment: @VonC But I feel like it should still be this same question... this question does not assume I have only a permission change in the file I am trying to commit (in fact, I was never trying to `git add -p` such a file). Do you still think I should open a new question?

Comment: Yes, with a link back to this one,  and a lot more details, like git version as well as a small she'll transcript illustrating the persisting issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set `git --global core.autocrlf` to `false`.
Then clone again your repo, and check the value of `core.autocrlf`:

```
cd /path/to/new/clone
git config core.autocrlf
```

(no --global)

Finally, try again your `git add -p` (after reporting your modification in your new working tree).

Regarding hunk management, see also "[Unexpected result in `git-diff`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40552165/6309)".

---

> "Your edited hunk does not apply".

```
diff --git a/<file-a> b/<file-b> > 
index <short-hash-a>..<short-hash-b> 100644 
--- a/<file-a> 
+++ b/<file-b>
<changes>
```

If there was no changes (only in permission), adding a "patch" in that case does not make sense: you just `git add` the file (no `-p`)

But if there are changes, the question the OP mentioned "[`git add --interactive “Your edited hunk does not apply”`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3268596/6309)" remains the reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried what you have said. The local value for `core.autocrlf` is returned as `false` in my new cloned repo, but `git add -p` in manual edit mode still returns the same error (again without any changes made to the edit file).

Comment: @Atreyu What is the result of `git diff -- afile`? (with `afile` the one you are trying `to add -p`)

Comment: I get 
`diff --git a/<file-a> b/<file-b>` 
`index <short-hash-a>..<short-hash-b> 100644`
`--- a/<file-a>`
`+++ b/<file-b>`
`<changes>`

Comment: I'm a bit confused, I have content changes in my file, and I don't recall changing permissions to the file... is this a quirk in Windows?

Comment: @Atreyu in your case, if you see only 100644 and actual content changes, this is not a permission issue (I revised my answer to make it clearer). Regarding permissions on Windows, see as an illustration http://stackoverflow.com/a/41310550/6309.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134336/discussion-between-atreyu-and-vonc).