# git CLI commands for stage/unstage hunks/lines like sourcetree

Tags: git, command-line-interface, atlassian-sourcetree

Sourcetree makes it easy to stage and unstage hunks. And also easy to select particular lines from within a hunk and stage or unstage them. I am trying to figure out how to do the same from the command line.

I tried doing each operation in sourcetree with the command history panel showing. It doesn't show any commands when I perform these operations. For other operations it works fine.

On the command line, I use `git add` in interactive mode, choose the patch option and then select a file with a multiline change in it. The prompt is: "Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]?". If I choose the '?' option it outputs this help text:

```
y - stage this hunk
n - do not stage this hunk
q - quit; do not stage this hunk or any of the remaining ones
a - stage this hunk and all later hunks in the file
d - do not stage this hunk or any of the later hunks in the file
g - select a hunk to go to
/ - search for a hunk matching the given regex
j - leave this hunk undecided, see next undecided hunk
J - leave this hunk undecided, see next hunk
k - leave this hunk undecided, see previous undecided hunk
K - leave this hunk undecided, see previous hunk
s - split the current hunk into smaller hunks
e - manually edit the current hunk
? - print help
```

The 's' option looks like the right one for staging individual lines out of the hunk. However, when I enter it, git just outputs the help text again.

Can anyone tell me where in the docs I should be looking?

Comment: Actually you did everything right. This might happen if the hunk is too small already, than it can't be splitted into smaller hunks.

Comment: The same hunk can be split in sourcetree.

Comment: I don't know SourceTree. Please try to manually edit ('e') the hunk and see what happens.

Comment: I added a '+' to the start of one line in a multiline change and saved the file.  Got this output: Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,j,J,g,e,?]? e
error: patch failed: changeme.txt:1
error: changeme.txt: patch does not apply
Your edited hunk does not apply. Edit again (saying "no" discards!) [y/n]?

Comment: Yes this can happen. Here is a related problem and how yo fix it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268596/git-add-interactive-your-edited-hunk-does-not-apply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

late to the party, but it might help others looking for a solution.

git tends to add lines in close proximity to the same hunk - if you want to stage code line by line, you can edit the hunks in interactive mode.

Once the file is modified, type:

```
git add -p
```

And now, instead of `s` you can type `e`.

Which brings you into an edit mode to change the hunk.

If you find a particular line you want to keep for staging in this particular hunk, make sure to leave its `+` and `-` in there and edit the others as described in the quick guide.

### Example time

Let's say I have following changes:

```
-  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
-  getPageTimeout: 60000
+  allScriptsTimeout: 180000,
+  getPageTimeout: 180000
```

However I only want to stage the first changed line. As explained above type `git add -p` and select `e`

Within the editor, change the `-` to a space and remove the lines you do not want staged.

Let's say I want only `+  allScriptsTimeout: 180000,` to be staged, I change the file to this:

```
-  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
   getPageTimeout: 60000
+  allScriptsTimeout: 180000,
```

And there we go, just one line staged, ready to be committed.

Albeit cumbersome, it is definitely possible to add individual lines within git CLI :)