# Staging a renamed attribute using hunk edit mode

Tags: git, git-patch

I'm trying to use 'git add -p' to commit only a part of my code. In the diff below I want to rename 'model' to 'sharedData' (thus, removing the model line and adding the sharedData-line).

```
@@ -58,9 +60,11 @@
        </div>
    `
 })

 export class PanelComponent implements OnInit, OnPanelAction, OnDestroy {
-   @Input() data: any;
-   @Input() model: any;
+   @Input() sharedData: any;
+   @Input() model: Wrapper<any>;
+   @Input() window: string;
+
    @Input() map: Map.WindowMapper;
    @Input() modules: any[];
```

I've tried adding unnecessary lines to context (adding a space) with multiple setting, but I get 'Your edited hunk does not apply.':

```
@@ -58,9 +60,12 @@
@@ -58,12 +60,12 @@
                </div>
        `
 })

 export class PanelComponent implements OnInit, OnPanelAction, OnDestroy {
        @Input() data: any;
-       @Input() model: any;
+       @Input() sharedData: any;
        @Input() model: Wrapper<any>;
        @Input() window: string;

        @Input() map: Map.WindowMapper;
        @Input() modules: any[];
```

Removing context lines did also not work:

```
 @@ -58,9 +60,8 @@
                </div>
        `
 })

 export class PanelComponent implements OnInit, OnPanelAction, OnDestroy {
-       @Input() model: any;
+       @Input() sharedData: any;
        @Input() map: Map.WindowMapper;
        @Input() modules: any[];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git add --interactive "Your edited hunk does not apply"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268596/git-add-interactive-your-edited-hunk-does-not-apply)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Edit hunk" view says the following:

```
 # To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
 # To remove '+' lines, delete them.
 # Lines starting with # will be removed.
```

You want to keep the *data* attribute, so you need to change the leading "-" of that line to a space - make sure not just to remove the "-", even if that might look the same if you are using tabs.

Additional you do not want to add the attributes *model* and *window*, so just delete that lines. Do the same for the empty line if you don't want to add it.

The result should look like this:

```
  export class PanelComponent implements OnInit, OnPanelAction, OnDestroy {
     @Input() data: any;
-    @Input() model: any;
+    @Input() sharedData: any;
     @Input() map: Map.WindowMapper;
     @Input() modules: any[];
```

In both of your examples you are changing the context so git cannot recognize the correct location:

The first example contains the *model* and the *window* attribute without the plus sign at the beginning, which means to git that they should exist in the previous code. In the second example the previously existing attribute *data* is missing, which should be there for the correct context.