# How to edit patch for git add in vscode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-patch

I tried to edit `git add --patch` using interactive git add.

so first `git add -i` then `What for>p` then `e` for editing patch
(I set my settings for editor with vscode not vim)

```js
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide.
@@ -1,5 +1,16 @@
 import React from "react";
 
+export type Question = {
+  category: string;
+  correct_answer: string;
+  difficulty: string;
+  incorrect_answers: string[];
+  question: string[];
+  type: string[];
+};
+
+export type QuestionState = Question & { answer: string[] };
+
 export enum Difficulty {
   EASY = "easy",
   MEDIUM = "medium",
# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
# 
# If the patch applies cleanly, the edited hunk will immediately be
# marked for staging.
# If it does not apply cleanly, you will be given an opportunity to
# edit again.  If all lines of the hunk are removed, then the edit is
# aborted and the hunk is left unchanged.
```

so I was trying to edit my patch(for spliting block of code), what I want is excluding `export type QuestionState = Question & { answer: string[] };` from my commit. (because I want to make commit only export type Question)

but when I did delete `export type QuestionState = Question & { answer: string[] };` (like below code in editor)

and save and exit editor(with shortcut cmd+w).

```js
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide.
@@ -1,5 +1,16 @@
 import React from "react";
 
+export type Question = {
+  category: string;
+  correct_answer: string;
+  difficulty: string;
+  incorrect_answers: string[];
+  question: string[];
+  type: string[];
+};

 export enum Difficulty {
   EASY = "easy",
   MEDIUM = "medium",
# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
# 
# If the patch applies cleanly, the edited hunk will immediately be
# marked for staging.
# If it does not apply cleanly, you will be given an opportunity to
# edit again.  If all lines of the hunk are removed, then the edit is
# aborted and the hunk is left unchanged.
```

I got an error like this

```
error: patch failed: react-quiz/src/API.ts:1
error: react-quiz/src/API.ts: patch does not apply
Your edited hunk does not apply. Edit again (saying "no" discards!) [y/n]? Your edited hunk does not apply. Edit again (saying "no" discards!) [y/n]? Your edited hunk does not apply. Edit again (saying "no" discards!) [y/n]? y
```

How can I apply edit patch? I can not figure out what is the problem.

Comment: The empty line above `export enum Difficulty {` should be removed. It does not exist before editing and it does not belong to the patch (as there is no leading `+`).

Comment: @ste See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48427836/6309

Comment: @ElpieKay Thanks! that’s the point, now it works

Comment: @VonC this is also what I want , Thanks