# VSCode Git exit & save commit editor?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have Git Bash installed on Windows 10, I'm following this video https://youtu.be/MIFQwHlEI9o?t=602 on using git inside VSCode, he's picking pieces from a commit using checkout with the -p option:

```
$ git checkout 0903304 index.html -p
diff --git b/index.html a/index.html
index 3ebbb46..d95bb1a 100644
--- b/index.html
+++ a/index.html
@@ -10,6 +10,10 @@
     <ul>
         <li>Item one</li>
     </ul>
+
+    <p>Paragraph one</p>
+    <h1>A title</h1>
+    <div><p>Some text</p></div>

 </body>
 </html>
\ No newline at end of file
Apply this hunk to index and worktree [y,n,q,a,d,e,?]
```

when I enter "e" the file is loaded with both versions and my cursor is automatically placed in the editor. After making my changes and CTRL+S to save I can't exit. I've tried q, ESC, CTRL+X, wq, :wq, :x! nothing works but closing the file with the "x" but then I get:

```
Your edited hunk does not apply. Edit again (saying "no" discards!) [y/n]?       0 [sig] bash 987! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to win32 process (pid 6340)
```

Answer (score 9):

I finally figured this out, I followed the Microsoft guide for Git patch/diff mode https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/versioncontrol/ and this stackoverflow post for correctly editing the hunk: [git add --interactive "Your edited hunk does not apply"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268596/git-add-interactive-your-edited-hunk-does-not-apply/48427836#48427836)
Then used the following when editing the patch:

1. Save the file as with any other file <kbd>CTRL+S</kbd>
2. <kbd>CTRL+W</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to exit after making the changes and return you to the terminal

Answer (score 1):

I just saved the changes in the editor and closed it.
Fixation has taken place. Then synchronized the changes