# Vim move line up,down,left,right

Tags: vim, netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

In netbeans with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> we can move the line and it contents to LEFT, UP, RIGHT, DOWN ... how can I do this with vim !?

In linux netbeans is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>ARROW LEFT</kbd>, <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> to move !

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741814/move-entire-line-up-and-down-in-vim. Also what do you mean by move a line to the left/right?

Comment: You have netbeans ? if yes ... try CTRL LEFT, RIGHT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I do not have NetBeans but I guess (after googling) that by ctrl+right/left you mean to indent the selected block?

In that case you can use the `>>` and `<<` commands. Just either go the line you want to indent or select a block (using "v") and press `>` twice (remember about the shift key :)).

The others (move up/down) are clearly described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741814/move-entire-line-up-and-down-in-vim).

Hope that's what you're looking for!

Answer (score 2):

The following key maps your indentions in a Vim way (using alt + j and k keys) and formats the moved lines as according to their new position. Code stolen from http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_lines_up_or_down.

```
nnoremap <A-j> :m+<CR>==
nnoremap <A-k> :m-2<CR>==
inoremap <A-j> <Esc>:m+<CR>==gi
inoremap <A-k> <Esc>:m-2<CR>==gi
vnoremap <A-j> :m'>+<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap <A-k> :m-2<CR>gv=gv
```

Comment: On a Mac <A-something> doesn't work using Alt key. Replace with <C-something> and use Ctrl key.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Zenzen's answer, you can do for example Esc+5+<< to have 5 lines below the cursor shifted to the left by a tab space.