# Move current line (up/down) to one position in Vim

Tags: vim, editor, vi

Sometimes I want to swap current line with line up or below in vim. I can do it with commands `:m+1` or `:m-1`. However it is too wordy. Is there shorter way doing the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move entire line up and down in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741814/move-entire-line-up-and-down-in-vim)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Tim Pope's [unimpaired.vim - Pairs of handy bracket mappings](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590) and my own [LineJuggler plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4140) provide (among others; my plugin has a focus on line moves and copies, whereas Tim's has a mixture of useful stuff) `[e` and `]e` mappings to move the current line / selection above or below. These don't clobber the default register, as `ddp` et al. would do.

Answer (score 7):

give this a try:

`ddp` and `ddkP`

if it gives what you want. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Give mappings a chance:

```
nnoremap <leader>k :move-2<CR>==
nnoremap <leader>j :move+<CR>==
xnoremap <leader>k :move-2<CR>gv=gv
xnoremap <leader>j :move'>+<CR>gv=gv
```

Answer (score 1):

Vim has the `:move` command that allows you to move one line.

For instance, `:m +1` will move the current line down.

I have these mappings in my `.vimrc` :

```
" move the lines of visual mode up or down
" JK to move and keep a correct indentation (with =)
" <up><down> to move keeping the correct indentation
vnoremap <silent> J :m '>+1<cr>gv=gv
vnoremap <silent> <down> :m '>+1<cr>gv
vnoremap <silent> K :m '<-2<cr>gv=gv
vnoremap <silent> <up> :m '<-2<cr>gv
```

With these lines, if you select a bunch of lines in visual mode, and then press `<up>` or `<down>` arrows, the lines will be moved up or down (and you will stay in the same visual selection thanks to the `gv` at the end).

`J` and `K` are almost the same, but they keep and autoindentation, using the `=` operator (`gv=` autoindents the last visual selection).

For sure, i encourage you to do modify the keys that are mapped to your own preferences. These are just mine. Also, copy-pasting without understanding is probably a bad idea. If you understand that mapping, you could check help pages for `:m`, `gv` and `=`.