# What the D-S-Up means in vim?

Tags: vim, macros, keyboard-shortcuts

I find a .vimrc file config:

```
" Move selection up/down (add =gv to reindent after move)
:vmap <D-S-Up> :m-2<CR>gv
:vmap <D-S-Down> :m'>+<CR>gv
```

I know the D-S-Up must be a key, but what is the key?

I type:

```
:help D-S-Up
```

nothing happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `:help key-notation` tells you the meaning of all those `<key>` notations.
2. You can't expect `:help D-S-Up` to do anything because:

   - it doesn't follow established patterns like `i_ctrl-r`,
   - it is a custom mapping and Vim only provides documentation for its own commands.
3. `<D>` is the `Cmd` key on Mac keyboards, `<S>` is the `Shift` key, and `<Up>` is the `Up` arrow key.

   So `<D-S-Up>` means `Cmd` + `Shift` + `Up`.
4. The `Cmd` key only works in the MacVim GUI.
5. Non-portable mappings are worthless.
6. One should use `:xmap` or `:xnoremap` for visual mode mappings, not `:v*`.
7. Non-recursive mappings should be used by default *unless* one really wants recursion.
8. Using someone else's `vimrc` is a *bad* idea.
9. By the way, here are enhanced versions of those mappings:

   ```
   nnoremap <silent> <D-S-Up>   :<C-u>move-2<CR>==
   nnoremap <silent> <D-S-Down> :<C-u>move+<CR>==
   xnoremap <silent> <D-S-Up>   :move-2<CR>gv=gv
   xnoremap <silent> <D-S-Down> :move'>+<CR>gv=gv
   ```

   where:

   - `<silent>` prevents the commands in the mapping from echoing useless info,
   - `<C-u>` removes any default range inserted by Vim,
   - `move-2<CR>` is a more readable version of `m-2<CR>`,
   - `==` re-indents the line,
   - `gv=gv` reselects the lines, re-indents them, and re-selects them again.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Move entire line up and down in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741814/move-entire-line-up-and-down-in-vim)

In an answer you can read (concerning the line `:vmap <D-S-Up> :m-2<CR>gv`):

> According to the shortcuts above, pressing Cmd-Shift-Up/Down will shift the block selection up/down. "D" is the Command key in MacVim, for Windows try "C" (Control), or "A" (Alt) (eg.  would be Control Alt f).

Since I don't have a Mac myself, I can't check, but it's most certainly true.