# Moving multiple lines in vim visual mode

Tags: vim, text, text-editor, vim-plugin

After pressing <kbd>v</kbd> and entering *visual mode* in [vim](/questions/tagged/vim), I would like to move those lines up a few rows. The solution [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741814/move-entire-line-up-and-down-in-vim) does not suit me as I would like to move lines *visually,* i.e. I don't want to be typing <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>+`n` as I don't know the value of `n`. *Is there are keyboard shortcut that would allow me to move the **selected** lines in visual mode one line at time down or up by pressing the key sequence?*

[image: Sample with selected lines]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's no built-in command for that but you could build one with `:help :move`.

### First iteration

```
" move selected lines up one line
xnoremap <somekey>  :m-2<CR>

" move selected lines down one line
xnoremap <otherkey> :m'>+<CR>
```

#### Move line up

What we want is to move the selection between the line above the current one and the second line above the current one:

```
             current line - 2 > aaa
             current line - 1 > aaa
                 current line > bbb <
                                bbb < visual selection
                                bbb <
                                ccc
                                ccc
```

The right ex command is thus `:m-2`.

#### Move line down

The current line is not a good starting point because it's the first line in our selection but we can use the `'>` mark (end of visual selection):

```
                                aaa
                                aaa
                 current line > bbb <
                                bbb < visual selection
      end of visual selection > bbb <
  end of visual selection + 1 > ccc
                                ccc
```

The right ex command is thus `:m'>+1`.

But we lost our selection so we have to do `gv` to get it back before moving the selection again. Not good.

### Second iteration

```
" move selected lines up one line
xnoremap <somekey>  :m-2<CR>gv

" move selected lines down one line
xnoremap <otherkey> :m'>+<CR>gv
```

Where we simply append `gv` to the end of our previous mapping. Neat. But what about fixing indentation as we go?

### Third and last iteration

```
" move selected lines up one line
xnoremap <somekey>  :m-2<CR>gv=gv

" move selected lines down one line
xnoremap <otherkey> :m'>+<CR>gv=gv
```

Where appending `=gv` to our mappings fixes the indentation (`:help v_=`) and reselects our lines.

[image: demo]

### Bonus normal mode mappings

```
" move current line up one line
nnoremap <somekey>  :<C-u>m-2<CR>==

" move current line down one line
nnoremap <otherkey> :<C-u>m+<CR>==
```

Comment: Amazing answer thanks very much. To map those moves to *Alt + arrow* can I just type `<Alt+Up>`?

Comment: Ideally yes but `<Alt>` is not reliable at all.